# 404 curl_error when i add PayPal-Mock-Response in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, php-curl

The following code works with no errors for a successful paypal transaction (without paypal-mock-response ).

When i added `"PayPal-Mock-Response:{\"mock_application_codes\": \"MALFORMED_REQUEST\"}"` in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to test different senarios as paypal suggests  at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/request-headers/#test-api-error-handling-routines
`curl_error()` returns `The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found`

The problem has to be the way i add `"PayPal-Mock-Response:{\"mock_application_codes\": \"MALFORMED_REQUEST\"}"` in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` but i haven't figure it out yet.

**paypal_button.php**

```
<?php
    define("BASE_URL", "http://my_website.com/paypal_test/");
    define("PayPal_CLIENT_ID", "my_paypal_client_id");
    define("PayPal_BASE_URL", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/");
?>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    paypal.Button.render(
    {
        env: 'sandbox',
        client: {
            sandbox:    '<?php echo PayPal_CLIENT_ID; ?>'
        },
        commit: true,
        style: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            fundingicons: 'true'
        },
        // payment() is called when the button is clicked
        payment: function(data, actions) 
        {
            // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: {
                                total: '200',
                                currency: 'EUR'
                            }
                        } ]
                },
                experience: {
                    input_fields: {
                        no_shipping: 1
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) 
        {
            // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() 
            {
                console.log('Payment Complete!');
                window.location = "<?php echo BASE_URL ?>process.php?paymentID="+data.paymentID+"&payerID="+data.payerID+"&token="+data.paymentToken
            });
        }
    }, '#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
define("BASE_URL", "http://my_website.com/paypal_test/");
define("PayPal_CLIENT_ID", "my_paypal_client_id");
define("PayPal_SECRET", "my_paypal_secret");
define("PayPal_BASE_URL", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/");
try
{
    function paypalCheck($paymentID, $payerID, $paymentToken)
    {
        // Request Access Token
        $ch = curl_init();
        $clientId = PayPal_CLIENT_ID;
        $secret = PayPal_SECRET;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, PayPal_BASE_URL.'oauth2/token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId . ":" . $secret);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
        if( !($result = curl_exec($ch)) ) // If curl didn't succeed
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            echo "curl error during access token recieval = " . curl_error($curl);
            echo '</pre>';
            curl_close($curl);
        }
        else // If curl succeed get access token from result
        {
            $json = json_decode($result);
            $accessToken = $json->access_token;
            echo "access token was recieved succesfully and it is = " . $accessToken;

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, PayPal_BASE_URL.'payments/payment/' . $paymentID);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'PayPal-Mock-Response: {\"mock_application_codes\":\"MALFORMED_REQUEST\"}'
               // If we remove PayPa-Mock-Response line it works
            ));


            if( !($response = curl_exec($curl)) ) // If curl didn't succeed
            {
                // The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
                echo '<pre>';
                echo "curl error = " . curl_error($curl);
                echo '</pre>';

                //it's empty of course
                $result = json_decode($response);
                echo '<pre>';
                echo "result with curl error = " . $result;
                echo '</pre>';

                curl_close($curl);
            }
            else // If curl succeeded
            {        
                $result = json_decode($response);
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($result);
                echo '</pre>';

                $state = $result->state;
                curl_close($curl);
                if($state == 'approved') return true;
                else return false
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    if(!empty($_GET['paymentID']) && !empty($_GET['payerID']) && !empty($_GET['token']) )
    {
        $paymentID = $_GET['paymentID'];
        $payerID = $_GET['payerID'];
        $token = $_GET['token'];
        $paypalCheck=paypalCheck($paymentID, $payerID, $token);

        if($paypalCheck) echo "Success";
        else echo "Failure";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Some of the get parameters are missing or are empty";
    }

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

The print_r($result) from a transaction without PayPal-Mock-Response in case it helps:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => PAY-8JU54317DF169510YLNYKGKI
    [intent] => sale
    [state] => approved
    [cart] => 9E037228C8147091B
    [payer] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payment_method] => paypal
            [status] => VERIFIED
            [payer_info] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [email] => shashasha@gmail.com
                    [first_name] => panos
                    [last_name] => papepis
                    [payer_id] => PCVE6KXLWZWV2
                    [shipping_address] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [recipient_name] => panos papepis
                        )

                    [phone] => 3063691955
                    [country_code] => GR
                )

        )

    [transactions] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [amount] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [total] => 200.00
                            [currency] => EUR
                            [details] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [subtotal] => 200.00
                                )

                        )

                    [payee] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [merchant_id] => WLYWH4ZE3BUTW
                        )

                    [soft_descriptor] => PAYPAL *TESTFACILIT
                    [item_list] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [shipping_address] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [recipient_name] => panos papepis
                                )

                        )

                    [related_resources] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [sale] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 9MM47166KB525480R
                                            [state] => completed
                                            [amount] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [total] => 200.00
                                                    [currency] => EUR
                                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [subtotal] => 200.00
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [payment_mode] => INSTANT_TRANSFER
                                            [protection_eligibility] => ELIGIBLE
                                            [protection_eligibility_type] => ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE
                                            [transaction_fee] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [value] => 7.15
                                                    [currency] => EUR
                                                )

                                            [parent_payment] => PAY-8JU54317DF169510YLNYKGKI
                                            [create_time] => 2018-08-12T21:14:55Z
                                            [update_time] => 2018-08-12T21:14:55Z
                                            [links] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/9MM47166KB525480R
                                                            [rel] => self
                                                            [method] => GET
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/9MM47166KB525480R/refund
                                                            [rel] => refund
                                                            [method] => POST
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8JU54317DF169510YLNYKGKI
                                                            [rel] => parent_payment
                                                            [method] => GET
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [soft_descriptor] => PAYPAL *TESTFACILIT
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [create_time] => 2018-08-12T21:14:17Z
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8JU54317DF169510YLNYKGKI
                    [rel] => self
                    [method] => GET
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the `HTTP404` and the official [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/request-headers/#test-with-negative-testing) ...

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, PayPal_BASE_URL.'payments/payment/' . $paymentID. '/execute');
```

the `CURLOPT_URL` seems to be missing the trailing `/execute`, as the verb.

and concerning that `HTTP400` ... it might be required to first [create](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_create) a payment (and remembering the paymentId) and then to [execute](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_execute) that payment - while passing back the corresponding paymentID.

Comment: isn't the payment created when user clicks the paypal button,fill his credentials and choose pay?

Comment: @profchaos how shall a login create a payment? what is being passed along there is in best case a payment request. it is only logical, that one cannot execute what not had been created, in the first place. while the API does not return any new paymentId, one can assume that there is no payment in progress, which one can settle by it's execution.

Comment: What you say is logical...i will try to create it first. But why if i remove the PayPal-Mock-Response there are no curl errors?