# PayPalRestSDK: Mock Response Instrument_Declined response when capturing order

Tags: laravel, paypal, guzzle, paypal-rest-sdk

I've been struggling to mock the `'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED'` issue, which according to Paypal is an usual error after attempting to capture an order (https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).

Correctly setting the header to mock the response will help me to simulate other errors from the docs https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/test-and-go-live/simulation-tests/#orders.

I'm using Laravel back end and React front end.

I have already gotten the expected  mocked response using `axios` and calling in the front-end:

```
return axios
    .post(
        `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/${orderID}/capture`,
        {},
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
                "PayPal-Mock-Response":
                    '{"mock_application_codes":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED"}',
            },
        }
    )
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
```

However, I don't want to expose accessToken into the front end, I'd prefer to do everything in the back-end with `GuzzleHtttp`.

I've already had a positive response - with `'status': 'COMPLETED'` *without adding `PayPal-Mock-Response` header* like so:

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request(
        'POST',
        'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/' . $paypalOrderId . '/capture',
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
                // 'PayPal-Mock-Response' => json_encode(["mock_application_codes" => "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED"]),
                // 'PayPal-Mock-Response' => "['mock_application_codes':'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED]",
            ],
        ],
    );

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

But when adding the `PayPal-Mock-Response` header like shown in the commented code from above, both attemps have returned this exception:

> "message": "Client error: `POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/9HG50866FU785784C/capture`
> resulted in a `404 Not Found` response",
> "exception": "GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException",
> "file": "C:\xampp\htdocs\react\React-Laravel\vinos-gdl\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php",

This exception, I'm sure has to do to the way I'm passing the `PayPal-Mock-Response` header into the `Guzzle` http call but I can't find the way to do it correctly.

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE SOLVED****

Ok the way to go is sending the `header` like so:

`'PayPal-Mock-Response' => json_encode(["mock_application_codes" => "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED"]),`

I dunno if I had any typo but I finally got it. I also used `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` to get a `500 response` from server and built a `catch` for every situation:

```
} catch (ClientException $e) {

            if ($e->hasResponse()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'msg' => 'Client Exception',
                    'error' => json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()),
                ], 400);
            }
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Client Exception',
                'request' => $e->getRequest(),
                $e->hasResponse() ? $e->getResponse() : ""
            ]);
            // return response()->json(['msg' => 'Server Error', 'error' => report($e)]);
        } catch (BadResponseException $e) {

            if ($e->hasResponse()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'msg' => 'Uknown Exception',
                    'error' => json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()),
                ], 500);
            }
            return response()->json([
                'msg' => 'Uknown Exception',
                'request' => $e->getRequest(),
                $e->hasResponse() ? $e->getResponse() : ""
            ]);
        }
```

Thanks for the ones who commented.

Comment: have you tried sending a curl request via terminal as see if it works, as it is sending 404

Comment: Yep, sending `curl` request works but is a lot of mess. I'd prefer to test using the backend..

Comment: then you can try using json request option as well, https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json

Answer (score 0):

```
            "PayPal-Mock-Response":
                '{"mock_application_codes":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED"}',
```

...

```
            // 'PayPal-Mock-Response' => "['mock_application_codes':'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED]",
```

There is a difference betwen `{}` (JSON object) and `[]` (JSON array).

What you have inside the brackets is not an array, so its syntax is invalid. It doesn't map to anything PayPal expects, hence the 404.

Comment: the question code seems correct as I believe @FerToasted is using any one of them and json_encode will provide the given format, I believe if it is throwing 404 then the $orderId is not in their records or something like FerToasted might be trying before order is set in paypal

Comment: Nope, not the `$orderId` that's the exactly `response` I'm getting from the `createOrder` method and using that same `$orderID` when using the method without the `PayPal-Mock-Response` the method works correctly, so It's about the syntax most sure...

Comment: Apparently the syntax for this header is not that usual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812242/404-curl-error-when-i-add-paypal-mock-response-in-curlopt-httpheader. I'll by trying with differente combinations since it appears to be required to pass a `string` instead a `Json Object` nor a `Json Array`